# Configure jest into exist react native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs

I have an app and want to add some snapshots tests,
it's my first shot to work in testing stuff,
So after trying to run jest they ask for Mock packages I used or something so I add mocking jest for them

and run `test`

I got the under error.

Is my configuration good? or I miss something?

```
 console.error
    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

    Check the render method of `App`.
        in App
 console.error
    The above error occurred in the <Context.Provider> component:
        in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer))
        in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (created by ForwardRef(NavigationContainer))
        in ThemeProvider (created by ForwardRef(NavigationContainer))
        in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (created by App)
        in QueryClientProvider (created by App)
        in App

.....
```

here's my config and test
App.tsx

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import './src/i18n';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AuthNavigator from './src/navigation/AuthNavigator';
import RootNavigator from './src/navigation/RootNavigator';
import {StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import {QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query';
import {useAuth} from './src/stores/authStore';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react-native';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: 'https://********@*******.ingest.sentry.io/****',
});

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

export default function App() {
  const isLogin = useAuth(state => state.isLogin);

  async function requestUserPermission() {
    let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('device_token');
    if (!fcmToken) {
      await messaging().requestPermission();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    requestUserPermission();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      remoteMessage?.data?.type === 'waiting'
        ? queryClient.invalidateQueries('getBookingsList')
        : null; // refetch Booking list when receive notification from server
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />
        {isLogin ? <RootNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}
```

_ *test* _/App-test.tsx

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import {waitFor} from '@testing-library/react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('App', () => {
  it('renders app stack correctly', async () => {
    const component = <App />;
    await waitFor(() => renderer.create(component));
  });
});
```

jest.setup.js

```
import mockRNDeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info/jest/react-native-device-info-mock';
import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock';

jest.mock('@sentry/react-native', () => ({init: () => jest.fn()}));

jest.mock('react-native-device-info', () => mockRNDeviceInfo);
require('react-native-reanimated/lib/reanimated2/jestUtils').setUpTests();
jest.mock('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage', () => mockAsyncStorage);

jest.mock('@react-native-firebase/messaging', () => {
  const module = () => {
    return {
      getToken: jest.fn(() => '1234'),
    };
  };
  module.AuthorizationStatus = {
    NOT_DETERMINED: -1,
    DENIED: 0,
    AUTHORIZED: 1,
    PROVISIONAL: 2,
  };

  return module;
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.7.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.5",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "i18next": "^20.3.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-i18next": "^11.11.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^7.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-query": "^3.19.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.9",
    "zustand": "^3.5.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^4.0.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.0-next.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^16"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "preset": "react-native",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
      "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules/"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native-community|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|@react-native|react-native-gesture-handler|react-native-device-info|/.*)"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */,
    "module": "commonjs" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */,
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
    "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */,
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    "jsx": "react-native" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */,
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    "noEmit": true /* Do not emit outputs. */,
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    "isolatedModules": true /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */,
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */,
    "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    "skipLibCheck": false /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already appear to be using `@testing-library/react-native` (which is good) - so I'd recommend switching to using their render method instead of react-native-renderer e.g.:

```
import { waitFor, render } from "@testing-library/react-native"

describe('App', () => {
  it('renders app stack correctly', async () => { 
     render(<App />)
// (If you want to check anything, you then can pick off the return of render like so:
// const {queryAllByA11yHint} = render(<App />)
  });
});
```

Regarding the actual question - the problem is that the renderer takes a component, not an element - if you change to what I showed above it will work, alternatively if you are still wanting to use your renderer it'd be like this:

```
describe('App', () => {
  it('renders app stack correctly', async () => {
    await waitFor(() => renderer.create(<App />));
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey! I tried both and i got this error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Comment: @OliverD Hm, might be best to make an expo snack to reproduce the problem to diagnose further as right now the imports look to be correct and this is the proper way to use the render (or renderer methods depending which library you lean towards)